# Variable (IBOutlet UITextView) that works in some methods but not others

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a view controller with this variable:

```
IBOutlet UITextView* chat
```

It works in some methods of the class but not for example in this method "chat" functions like I think it should:

```
    // We are being asked to display a chat message
- (void)displayChatMessage:(NSString*)message fromUser:(NSString*)userName ofType:(NSString*)type withKey:(NSString*)key {

    [chat appendTextAfterLinebreak:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", userName, message]];
    [chat scrollToBottom];

    NSLog(@"stuff to us %@: %@ type:  %@", userName, message, type);

}
```

Others like this one it doesn't:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == input) {
        // processs input
        [chatRoom  broadcastChatMessage:input.text fromUser:@"me" ofType:@"message"];
        NSLog(@"Broadcast Chat Room is:  %@", chatRoom);
        [chat appendTextAfterLinebreak:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me: %@",  input.text]];
        // clear input
        [input setText:@""];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

When I use breakpoints, the variable chat shows 0x00 when it's not working.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

.h:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <RoomDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UILabel* label;

    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *bbiOpenPopOver;

    UIPopoverController *popOverController;
    ServerListController *serverListController;
    Room* chatRoom;
    IBOutlet UITextView* chat;
    IBOutlet UITextField* input;
    Room *newRoom;


}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *bbiOpenPopOver;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popOverController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) ServerListController *serverListController;

@property(nonatomic,retain) Room* chatRoom;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView* chat;

-(IBAction)togglePopOverController;

@end
```

Comment: Does chat get set to nil at any point? How is chat declared in the header file?

Comment: @Paul.s  I didn't see anywhere that chat is set to nil but I will dig a little deeper.  There is one place where I do this:  chat.text = @"";  See my edit above for the header file.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry just seen your edit. Is there any reason you are accessing the ivar directly and not going through the getters/setters? It makes the memory management a lot easier if you use getters/setters and can help avoid these issues.

Comment: I'm self taught and havn't been exposed to a different way.  Do you have an example of a getter/setter that I could implement?

Comment: When chat shows 0x00, did you put the breakpointS before or after [chat append....]?

Comment: @user523234  I stepped through one of the methods that doesn't work and it remains the same throughout the lifespan of the method.  @Paul.s I found an example of the getter and setter.  I may try that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's going on.

In your `FirstViewController` you are declaring the internal variable (ivar):

```
IBOutlet UITextView* chat;
```

Then, additionally, your are declaring the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView* chat;
```

Unless you specify otherwise, each Objective-C property is supported by an auto-synthesized ivar whose name is the property name with the `_` prefix before it (`_chat` in this case).

So `FirstViewController` has two different ivars for the same thing: `chat` and `_chat`. I'm guessing the methods that work use `chat`, and the ones that fail use `_chat` or `self.chat` (which accesses `_chat` internally). That, or  the other way around.

My suggestion is that you get rid of all the ivars, and work only using the property accessors (`self.propertyName`). That makes properties immediate and easily distinguishable from local variables and *imho* results in more readable and maintainable code.

Note that you can declare properties both in the `.h` and in the `.m` files. Properties declared in the `.m` file will only be viewable from that file. I suggest you declare all the properties which are unneeded outside the class in the `.m` file. This keeps the interface of your ViewController lean and clean.

I personally only access ivars directly when I have to overload or override property accessors or if doing that would effectively increase performance (which is not so common).